# Breezejs 1.5.4 and 1.5.5 LinkeRelatedEntities for 1-To-1 Unidirectional Parent to Child Navigation Property throw a exception

Tags: breeze

Having this type of relation

```
Parent Entity
    Id
    ChildNavigationProperty    

Child Entity      
   Id // P-Key and F-Key to parent Entity
```

When Breeze is executing the `proto._linkRelatedEntities` function to link the related entities for the parent entity

it is doing this:

```
if (np.isScalar) {
   // n -> 1  eg: child: OrderDetail parent: Product
   // 1 -> 1 eg child: Employee parent: Employee 
   // ( only Manager, no DirectReports property)
   childToParentNp = np;
   unattachedChildren.forEach(function (child) {
       child.setProperty(childToParentNp.name, entity);
   });
}
```

This throw a exception because it try to find `ChildNavigationProperty` on the child entity and not the parent entity. `this[propertyName] = value;` where "this" is "child entity" and "propertyName" is "ChildNavigationProperty" and "value" is the "parent entity"

In Breeze v1.5.3 this is executed instead:

```
entity.setProperty(parentToChildNp.name, unattachedChildren[0]);
```

For me this look more correct, is it something I have mist?